# How to get alternate row using SQL query?

Tags: sql, sql-server-2014

I have a requirement which I need to produce the result that returns alternately 1 and 0.

```
SELECT * 
FROM 
    (SELECT
         id
         ,itemNo
         ,convert(int,tStationsType_id) as tStationsType_id
         ,tSpecSetpoint_descriptions_id
         ,SetpointValue
         ,rowEvenOdd 
     FROM 
         TEST S
     INNER JOIN
         (SELECT 
              itemNo AS IM, tStationsType_id as ST,
              ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION  BY itemNo ORDER BY itemNo) % 2 AS rowEvenOdd
          FROM TEST
          GROUP BY itemNo, tStationsType_id) A ON S.itemNo = A.IM
                                               AND S.tStationsType_id = A.ST) t
WHERE
    itemno = '1000911752202'
ORDER BY 
    tStationsType_id
```

The result I get is something like below.

I would like to produce alternate 1 and 0 in `rowEvenOdd`. However I notice it I can't get it alternate if I order by `tStationsType_id`.

So basically, what I want is when the

- StationsType_id = 2, then rowEvenOdd = 0
- StationsType_id = 3, then rowEvenOdd = 1
- StationsType_id = 6, then rowEvenOdd = 0
- StationsType_id = 8, then rowEvenOdd = 1
- StationsType_id = 10, then rowEvenOdd = 0

[image]

Can someone help me with this query?

Thanks.

Comment: `ROW_NUMBER` modulo (`%`) 2

Comment: yes i am using that too in sub query

Comment: is this sqlserver ? Which version

Answer (score 1):

If you just need alternating 0 and 1 in the result set, use `SEQUENCE` like this:

```
CREATE SEQUENCE EvenOdd
   START WITH 0
   INCREMENT BY 1
   MAXVALUE 1
   MINVALUE 0
   CYCLE;
GO
SELECT SalesId, NEXT VALUE FOR EvenOdd as EvenOddColumn FROM Sales
DROP SEQUENCE EvenOdd
```

To learn more, go to the MSDN page on sequences here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff878091.aspx

Comment: is this using store procedure?

Comment: SEQUENCE is a special type of database object.

Comment: I am not sure about this. i have never tried this. it seems i need to use store procedure instead of sql query

Comment: You can create sequence in the database once and then reuse it. That way you'll need just SELECT part of my script in your app.

Comment: This will not ensure the same value for rowEvenOdd each time the script is executed. It will simply rotate 0 and 1 for each row and each run, odd number of row will result in next run starting with a different value for EvenOdd, so not a valid solution. However I learned something new

Comment: @t-clausen.dk yes, I know that, but OP didn't mention that it have to be the same value for each row each time, I think it's purpose is something like coloring the grid lines in the app, so order is not important

Answer (score 0):

you can Use `case when then`

```
SELECT 

case
     when exists (SELECT 1 FROM  StationsTypeMaster 
      M WHERE  M.StationsType_id=A.StationsType_id)
     then 1
     else 0 end as rowEvenOdd 

,*
 FROM 
 (
 select id

  ,itemNo
  ,convert(int,tStationsType_id) as tStationsType_id
  ,tSpecSetpoint_descriptions_id
  ,SetpointValue
,rowEvenOdd from TEST S
inner join 
(select itemNo AS IM,tStationsType_id as ST,
ROW_NUMBER() OVER(PARTITION  BY itemNo ORDER BY itemNo)%2 AS rowEvenOdd
from TEST
group by itemNo,tStationsType_id

)A

on S.itemNo = A.IM
and S.tStationsType_id = A.ST) t
where itemno = '1000911752202'
order by tStationsType_id
```

Comment: its actually an example, the id is actually dynamic. so we might have more in the future.

Comment: @AmanMJ you can use master table to save ... as updated answer

Answer (score 0):

Use DENSE_RANK instead of ROW_NUMBER:

```
SELECT * FROM 
(  
  SELECT
    id,
    itemNo
    convert(int,tStationsType_id) as tStationsType_id,
    tSpecSetpoint_descriptions_id,
    SetpointValue,
    (DENSE_RANK() OVER(ORDER BY CAST(A.ST as INT)) - 1)%2 AS rowEvenOdd
  FROM
  TEST S
  JOIN
  (
    SELECT
      itemNo AS IM,
      tStationsType_id as ST
    FROM 
      TEST
    GROUP BY
      itemNo,tStationsType_id
    )A
  ON 
    S.itemNo = A.IM
    and S.tStationsType_id = A.ST
) t
WHERE
  itemno = '1000911752202'
ORDER BY
  tStationsType_id
```

Comment: this somehow return me all 0 in rowEvenOdd. I have tried this.

Comment: rowEvenOdd starts with 0 for first value of IM, 1 as second value, 0 as third value and 1 as fourth value. I moved the RowEvenOdd outside the subselect as i suspect it was messing with the result

Comment: somehow I still get all 0. Is it it happen because we might have multiple records for same IM and stationtypeid?

Comment: I had DENSE_RANK on IM instead of ST. Changed to ST now

Comment: i have added the IM and ST, however it still did not return proper alternate

Comment: The issue is that you have a numeric value declared as a varchar(I noticed from your fiddle). I have fixed it by casting. Should work now

Comment: hey it seems to work.let me try it with more data,thanks!